# Insert value in apex time field

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript

I want to insert the record in custom field whose data type is time.

Example:

```
obj o = new ojb();
o.StartTime__c = 10:20:00.000zCET;
```

but i am getting the error.

> Unexpected token '='.

I have tried with `10:20 AM`, `10:20 ,10:20:00.000Z` but no progress.

Please provide any suggestion either by apex or lightning.

Comment: It says ojb instead of obj. Wait, that doesn't make sense either. There is no such thing as obj in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm) will help you

Create an instance  of the time class as

```
Time myTime = Time.newInstance(hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Also if you are targeting custom object **ojb** make sure use *__c* at end while creating its instance